# Nodejs exec child process stdout not getting all the chunks

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send messages from my child process to main my process but some chunks are not being sent, possibly because the file is too big.

main process:

```
let response = ''
let error = ''
await new Promise(resolve => {
  const p = exec(command)
  p.stdout.on('data', data => {
    // this gets triggered many times because the html string is big and gets split up
    response += data
  })
  p.stderr.on('data', data => {
    error += data
  })
  p.on('exit', resolve)
})
console.log(response)
```

child process:

```
// only fetch 1 page, then quit
const bigHtmlString = await fetchHtmlString(url)
process.stdout.write(bigHtmlString)
```

I know the child process works because when I run the it directly, I can see the end of the file in in the console. But when I run the main process, I cannot see the end of the file. It's quite big so I'm not sure exactly what chunks are missing.

**edit**: there's also a new unknown problem. when I add a wait at the end of my child process, it doesn't wait, it closes. So I'm guessing it crashes somehow? I'm not seeing any error even with `p.on('error', console.log)`
example:

```
const bigHtmlString = await fetchHtmlString(url)
process.stdout.write(bigHtmlString)
// this never gets executed, the process closes. The wait works if I launch the child process directly
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000000))
```

Comment: I wonder if it's possible you might be notified of the child exit before the OS is done relaying you all the data via the streams.  Thus, you might resolve prematurely?  You could instrument things with logging to see if any more data arrives after you call `resolve()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did try commenting out `p.on('exit', resolve)` and leaving it hang forever and I'm still not getting the las chunks. Though maybe the program terminates and the stream is closed before the chunks have finished sending. How can I wait until all the chunks have sent?

Comment: I would suggest returning a stream from `fetchHtmlString()` and piping it to the `stdout`. That way, you will avoid writing a large amount of data at once and it will probably be slightly faster than the current solution

Comment: I think either Sebastian's suggestion about using `.pipe()` or writing your own code to handle drain like Tudor suggested is probably in order.  If all the bytes aren't getting there, then there's probably a problem in sending the bytes.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I would think the problem lies in in the main process, since when I launch the child process directly, it works perfectly

Comment: @jfriend00 no I'm awaiting the promise until exit, I also tested just console logging the chunks as they arrive and letting the promise never resolve, I'm still not getting all the chunks. I would be surprised if it's a promise issue, I work with promises a lot, but rarely with IO

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see the `await` before the `new Promise()`.  It's easy to get tricked when you don't show the larger context of the containing function.

Comment: @jfriend00 no problem, thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, then another thing I would suggest is to use `spawn` instead of `exec`. The latter buffers the output and flushes it when the process is ended (or the buffer is full) while `spawn` is streaming the output which is better for huge output like in your case

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek yes spawn fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion from the comments resolved the issue so I'm posting it as an answer.

I would suggest using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). The latter buffers the output and flushes it when the process is ended (or the buffer is full) while `spawn` is streaming the output which is better for huge output like in your case

Answer (score 2):

`process.stdout.write(...)` returns `true`/`false` depending on whether it wrote the string or not. If it returns false, you can listen() to the `drain` event to make sure it finishes.

Something like this:

```
const bigHtmlString = await fetchHtmlString(url);
const wrote = process.stdout.write(bigHtmlString);

if (!wrote){
  // this effectively means "wait for this
  // event to fire", but it doesn't block everything
  process.stdout.on('drain', ...doSomethingHere)
}
```

Comment: that didn't do anything different. just to be clear, I am getting around 10 chunks in my main process, so it's definitely writing, just not all of it. when I run my child process directly, I can see the end of the response `...</html>`, but for some reason in my main process i'm missing some chunks, maybe only the last one

Comment: it seems that wrote is true so thats why it doesnt do anything